# How to decode a webpage response in python

Tags: python, web, encoding, gzip

I decoded the gzip enecoding doing like this:

```
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=wepage_response)
decoded_str = str(gzipper)
```

and now the decoded_str looks like this:

```
<gzip 0\x82\x01\xcb\n\x01
\x00\xa0\x82\x01\xc40\x82\x01\xc0\x06\t+\x06\x01\x05\x05\x070\x01\x01\x04\x82\x0
1\xb10\x82\x01\xad0\x81\x96\xa2\x16\x04\x14J\xdd\x06\x16\x1b\xbc\xf6h\xb5v\xf5\x
81\xb6\xbbb\x1a\xbaZ\x81/\x18\x0f20140804010112Z0k0 ....>
```

How do I interpret this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `read()` the content from your `gzipper` instance:

```
import gzip
from cStringIO import StringIO

webpage_response = '\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xe6|\xdfS\x00\x03test.txt\x00\xcb\xc8T(\xc9H-J\xe5\x02\x00\xb6\x0b\x88\x9b\t\x00\x00\x00'
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(webpage_response))
decompressed_str = gzipper.read()

>>> decompressed_str
'hi there\n'
```

Comment: if i use gizpper.read() i get this error:      x = gzipper.read()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 254, in read
     self._read(readsize)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 288, in _read
     pos = self.fileobj.tell()   # Save current position
 exceptions.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell'

Comment: It looks like `wepage_response` is not a file-like object, but is instead a string. You can wrap `webpage_response` in a StringIO.StringIO object to get a file-like object.

Comment: @mihaii13 : I've updated my answer to show decompression from a string instead of a file